# How to make amplification circuit for WWVB PWM signal from Raspberry Pi

Tags: transistors, amplifier, passive-networks

[image]

I’m trying to follow this video since I’m experiencing the same problem with my WWVB radio controlled clocks (can’t get signal where I live) and thought it would be a good excuse to learn a bit about electronics. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SHGAEhnsYk

So far I have the clock syncing with the circuit above if I put the clock right on top of the ferrite rod. What I have done:

1. I’m using a different software to generate the signal since I have a Pi4 and the code used in the tutorial only works on Pi3. This is the code I’m running: https://github.com/apoluekt/raspberry-wwvb
2. I have the correct value of Ferrite rod + capacitor to get resonant frequency of 60KHz.

Now my issue: I want to do the amplification part of the tutorial, there is a schematic at around 9:50

[image]

I tried to wire up my circuit according to the schematic and it’s not working:

In my photo above if I put the yellow wire from the Raspberry (signal output from the Raspberry) into where it’s labeled “A” (connecting it to the Base of the transistor), then the signal output at the Collector is inverted (which makes sense for comment emitter configuration) and obviously the clock no longer syncs.

So first question I have: is the schematic missing a inverting component? And what would that look like?

Additionally, even if the amplifier part works and the signal isn’t inverted, the video says to never put Vcc above 3.3V: but the Raspberry is already at 3.3V, then wouldn't there be no voltage gain? How would the LC antenna have more range?

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated :)